# PHP register_globals how to remake script

Tags: php

I have script, which I need to remake. The Script uses register_globals in link

```
echo '<a href="index.php?month=' . ($month+1) . '&amp;year=' . $year .  '"> &gt;&gt;</a>'
```

So how to remake it to work without register_global
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$_REQUEST` global array to access to variables:

`($month+1)` is the same as `($_REQUEST['month']+1)`

Comment: change all variables on $_REQUEST[%variable_name%] as i wrote in my answer

Comment: REQUEST shouldn't be used unless you know you want to cover both GET and POST.. you should add that to your answer.

Comment: look for example i have following code:
<?php
  $month = 11;
  echo $month . '<a href="global.php?month=' . ($month-1).'">Link</a>';
?>
how can i repalce it to work without register_globals.

Comment: If I use:
<?php
  $month = 11;
  echo $month . '<a href="global.php?month=' . ($_REQUEST['month']-1).'">Link</a>';
?>
it doesn't work.

Comment: Because you must use it as $_REQUEST['month'] = 11;

Comment: If I use 
<?php
  $_GET['month'] = 11;
  echo $_GET['month'] . '<a href="global.php?month=' . ($_GET['month']-1).'">Link</a>';
?>
It doesn't work too...
The question is, how to rewrite this code to work (after click on link - decrement that number) without register_globals?

Comment: You overwrite "month" with 11 every time you request to your page

Answer (score 0):

There is a shorter way do make your code compatible with register_globals off. Put this code on the beginning of the script:

```
extract(array_merge($_POST, $_GET, $_FILES, $_COOKIE));
```

It's a bit of a hack, but it works :).

Comment: Yes, It works but I have to replace variables because if register_globas is on, it's dangerous...